# Why isn't eclipse compiling my web app?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

When I start my Tomcat server, linked to my Java EE project, I get the error listed below.  Two other people are using the same repository with Eclipse/Tomcat/Java and are not having any problems.   It creates my package hierarchy, but the classes are missing.  Tomcat develops my WEB-INF/classes/com folders, but the contents are all empty.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thank you.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/LightStanza-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.lightfoundryllc.lightstanza.login.LoginValidator] for bean with name 'loginValidator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/LightStanza-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lightfoundryllc.lightstanza.login.LoginValidator
```

Comment: are you running your tomcat server from within eclipse? or do you start your tomcat manually?

Comment: Yes, I am running tomcat from within eclipse. I get this error when I right-click on the server and press Start.

Comment: the problem is most likely the way that you have configured Eclipse.  Check the relevant Eclipse preferences.  (The problem *won't* be that Eclipse isn't compiling anything.  It will be that it is not putting the compiled classes in the place they need to be.)

Comment: @Stephen - thanks for your advice. I have looked through the eclipse settings, and nothing seems to stand out.  Did a file search for the .class files on my HD and am not able to find anything that was generated.

Comment: Is the project file in the repository? If so I bet you it contains an absolute path somewhere that doesn't exist on your box.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I set my environment variables for TOMCAT_HOME and PATH and things seem to be working now :).

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors to this page, could you post what you set them to?